# Closing an open shape (tyre-like shape)?

Tags: modeling

The add-on that creates a gear seems to be generating a shape that is not closed. If you see the screenshot below, the inside part is not closed. I selected two inside loops and then pressed `f`, but that generated faces inside the big circles (blocking the centre hole); Of course, that was not what I wanted. If I select only one segment from each of the two loops and then press `f`, it correctly generated the face that blocked the inside, but then, I would have to repeat it numerous times (lots of segments). In this case, is there an easy way to fill the gap?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In Edge select mode select both inside edge loops then RMB (right mouse button) to open contextual menu and choose the Bridge Edge Loops option.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog Thanks.

Comment: One can't help but wonder why the initial primitive isn't already a closed mesh at the outset. There may be use cases where it needs to be open, but it seems they couldn't be more common than the ones where it needs to be closed. I'm reminded of the fact that the "Suzanne" monkey primitive also isn't a closed mesh. The eyes are not merged with the head. In this case, it's because the number of spans in each part is different. It's strange to me that some of these primitives aren't manifold geometry. Especially when there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of adding fixed ones to the UI.

Comment: @R-800 Well, to me, people work in mysterious ways. It seems that this object came from an official add-on called ["Extra Objects"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html) (Gears by Michel J. Anders). I had found that it is not closed after creating an animation with it. At first I thought it was some noise, but on close inspection, it was just that the shape was not closed and the other side was showing.